# Transfer Desmume and No$GBA save file

Tags: emulation, desmume

I would like to copy my save files of Desmume and No$GBA emulator to another computer (the current HDD which contains these save file would die soon). But I don't really know which files / folders I must copy, because there is some different places where Desmume and No$GBA had created files.

NB : I use Windows 8.1, and want to export them to Windows 10 or Ubuntu 18.04

NB2 : No$GBA is also a DS-emulator, I use it because my computer works a little better with it than Desmume in few games, but I need to use Desmume for few other games because it can't run some DS EoL games (like *Pokemon B/W* or *Mario and Sonic at Olympics Games*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily transfer the save files between different OSs. But the things that you need to keep in mind while transferring save files are :-

- Emulator Version
- File name of the ROM (should be unchanged)

NO$GBA :
No$gba stores its save files as .sav file in the battery folder of the emulator.

DeSmuME :
Desmume stores its save files in the battery folder of the emulator as well.
But note that there are two types of files in DeSmuME, save states and save files. Save states are saved as .dsx format(x is any digit from 0-9) whereas Save files are saved as .dsv files.

Note : Difference between save files and save states for DeSmuME  - [Save file or save state](https://wiki.desmume.org/index.php?title=Savefile_or_savestate)